# Периодический вывод переменной из класса в форму

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть основная форма, на которой находится *textbox* в виде консоли. В эту консоль должна выводиться некоторая переменная, которая динамически изменяется в классе.

Основной класс формы и класс, изменяющий переменную, находятся в разных файлах. Попытки вызвать эту переменную из класса приводят к выводу в консоль её самого последнего значения, что вполне понятно для меня.

Как организовать событие, при котором переменная бы отсылала свое значение на форму и её можно было бы вывести в консоль? Для этого нужны события, делегаты, параллельное выполнение через invoke, наследование, или можно обойтись более простым вещами?

Comment: Простая вещь - используйте таймер.

Comment: @Igor  не совсем понял вас. Допустим, моя переменная переменилась в классе в неизвестный мне момент времени. Мне надо отдать данные на форму. А таймер вроде как опрашивает через равные промежутки.

Comment: @Тарас Колеско Что вы имеете в виду под GUI? Это WinForms?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow да, именно это я и имею ввиду.

Comment: @ТарасКолеско - Постарайтесь точнее сформулировать желательное поведение ("Мы не можем заглянуть к Вам в мозг и узнать что Вам нужно." (с)). Если обновление интерфейса должно происходить в момент изменения переменной - сделайте её свойством класса и добавьте в этот класс событие, которое выстреливает в `set` этого свойства. Тогда форма добавит к этому событию delegate со своим методом и этом методе обновит интерфейс.

Comment: @Igor спасибо, это звучит как то, что мне нужно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы считаете, что прописать простое событие, это очень сложно? Тут делов на пару строк кода.

```
delegate void UI();

class SomeClass
{
    public event UI UserEvent;
    void OnUserEvent()
    {
        UserEvent();
    }

    private String someVal;
    public String SomeVal{ 
        get {} 
        set 
        {
             someVal = value;
             OnUserEvent();
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Ну и в самой форме:

```
....
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SomeClass_object = new SomeClass();
    SomeClass_object.UserEvent += new UI(onChange);
}

private void onChange()
{
    textBox1.Text = "ffuuuuuu";
}
....
```